# UE5 - Simulate Physics causes Actor to fall through ground when player interacts

Tags: unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I've set up a simple code that allows the player to use a line trace to pick up objects and assign them to one of three sockets on the character mesh.
[image: picking up and dropping]
I then set up the ability for the player to cycle between items in 'pockets' and items in hand, as well as dropping the items.
[image: this is also repeated for the second pocket slot, its the same so i wont show it here.]
Everything works fine. The player can pick items up and drop them, as well as cycle them between hand and pocket, as long as 'Simulate Physics' is set to false on the item that is being picked up. Anything the player interacts with that has 'Simulate Physics' enabled falls through the floor upon interaction. [this is the physics settings of the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5DHx.png)

I need the code to allow me to pick up physics items. I believe that the 'Set Actor Enable Collision' is the issue as when this is not in the loop the Actor does not fall through the ground, however I need to disable the Actors collision with the player otherwise movement is hindered. I don't understand why the 'Attach Actor To Component' doesn't hold the Actor in place when the Actor 'Simulate Physics' is set to true.